# Selenium - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am trying to create a script that loops through a list of urls/links of products on a website. If the product is not available it will continue to the next product. So far I am able to loop through the list of product links but I am getting an error

```
This page isn’t working
www.bestbuy.ca redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I am using `driver.get(url)` to go to each url and I have included `driver.delete_all_cookies()` in my code aswell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395181/err-too-many-redirects-error-while-trying-to-login-through-a-webpage-that-uses-f

Comment: Looks like it will! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. You can put +! to any of my posts as a gratitude)))

Comment: Sorry I dont understand how to do that

Comment: No problem. Welcome to site.